# Remove line if field is duplicate

Tags: sed, awk

Looking for an awk (or sed) one-liner to remove lines from the output if the first field is a duplicate.

An example for removing duplicate lines I've seen is:

```
awk 'a !~ $0; {a=$0}'
```

Tried using it for a basis with no luck (I thought changing the $0's to $1's would do the trick, but didn't seem to work).

Comment: You asked to remove lines 'if the first field matches' ... what?  I've assumed 'the same value as the first field in some previous input line'; another person assumed 'some particular pattern'.  What did you intend?

Comment: Your changed version `awk 'a !~ $1; {a=$1}'` *works for me* for adjacent duplicates (e.g. a sorted file). **Jonathan Leffler's** version has the advantage that it will work to remove duplicates on an unsorted file, but at the expense of creating a potentially large array.

Comment: I think my main problem was that I was dealing with a few different types of field seperators and wasn't defining FS properly

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
awk '{ if (a[$1]++ == 0) print $0; }' "$@"
```

This is a standard (very simple) use for associative arrays.

Comment: That worked! I had another bug that I didn't realize as well that may have been giving me problems aswell. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

this  is how to remove duplicates

```
awk '!_[$1]++' file
```

Comment: Using '_' as the array name invites misunderstanding - but it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using Perl:

```
perl -ane 'print if ! $a{$F[0]}++' file
```

`-a` autosplits the line into the `@F` array, which is indexed starting at 0
The `%a` hash remembers if the first field has already been seen

---

This related solution assumes your field separator is a comma, rather than whitespace

```
perl -F, -ane 'print if ! $a{$F[0]}++' file
```

Answer (score 0):

it print the unique as well as single value of the duplicates

```
awk '!a[$1]++' file_name
```