# Delete duplicate content in .csv file?

Tags: linux, csv

I have a large .csv file containing two columns

A) Name B) Email

I want to delete duplicate emails. It needs to delete the whole line.

For example if my .csv file has the following

```
Ted     abc@efg.com
John     abc@efg.com
Dave     abc@efg.com
```

it will remove the two bottom lines and only contain

```
Ted     abc@efg.com
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk` you can check for duplicate values based upon the column a string resides:

```
awk '!x[$2]++' FS="," file.csv > deduped.csv
```

In the example above awk checks column 2 of a csv file delimited with `,`

Comment: Note: you can use `FS=" ", FS="\t", etc.` depending on how the columns are delimited.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604088/awk-remove-line-if-field-is-duplicate) answer:

```
awk '{ if (a[$2]++ == 0) print $0; }' filename.csv
```