# Getting uniqe value from the first N characters

Tags: awk, grep, uniq

I don't quite understand how to solve my problem even though I have been using `grep`, `uniq` and `sort` before. I would very much appreciate how to crack this up :)

I wanted to get the `uniq` of the first 6 characters from my input file and get the output as shown below. I don't know if it's `uniq`, `grep`, `awk` I need to use, maybe someone could give me a hand in this.

My file looks like this:

```
Field1     Filed2    Field3
value1   some_stuff  something
value2   another     fake  
value1   fake        value    
value3   blah        blah
value2   blah        fake 


Prefered output:

Field1    Field2    Field3
value1   some_stuff something
value2   another    fake
value3   blah       blah
```

Comment: It is always advisable to add your efforts along with samples too in your post @rockStar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove line if field is duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604088/remove-line-if-field-is-duplicate)

Comment: sorry guys, will do add it next time...quit bz doing stuff atm :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following,

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next} !a[substr($0,1,6)]++' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '
FNR==1{                     ##Checking condition if line is first then do following.
  print                     ##Printing current line which is first line of headers.
  next                      ##next will skip all further lines from here.
}                           ##Closing condition BLOCK here.
!a[substr($0,1,6)]++        ##Creating array named a whose index is first 6 characters and keeping its increment value.
                            ##awk works on function condition/pattern and action, no action mentioned here so print of line happened.
'  Input_file               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

In case your first field has only 6 characters then use following.

```
awk '!a[$1]++' Input_file
```

---

About the `!a[$1]++` part. Basically it checks if it had already stored in an array (named `x` here) the first column value on a previous line parsing.

If it is the case (`a[$1] != 0`), it doesn't output the line. Otherwise, it outputs it and stores it (`a[$1]++`, so `a[$1] = a[$1] + 1` therefore `a[$1]` will equal `1`) for the next lines parsing. See this [Unix answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159734/138686).

Comment: thanx this worked and also for the explaination, im saving this oneliner as i would be using it more often :)