# How to merge two fasta files and remove the duplicate information?

Tags: cat, fasta

I want to merge two fasta file and remove the duplicate information.

Here is some example

```
>Symbiotaphrina_buchneri|DQ248313|SH1641879.08FU|reps|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Xylonomycetes;o__Symbiotaphrinales;f__Symbiotaphrinaceae;g__Symbiotaphrina;s__Symbiotaphrina_buchneri
ACGATTTTGACCCTTCGGGGTCGATCTCCAACCCTTTGTCTACCTTCCTTGTTGCTTTGGCGGGCCGATGTTCGTTCTCGCGAACGACACCGCTGGCCTGACGGCTGGTGCGCGCCCGCCAGAGTCCACCAAAACTCTGATTCAAACCTACAGTCTGAGTATATATTATATTAAAACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTCTGGCATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAAATGCGATAAGTAATGTGAATTGCAGAATTCAGTGAATCATCGAATCTTTGAACGCACATTGCGCCCCTTGGTATTCCGAGGGGCATGCCTGTTCGAGCGTCATTTCACCACTCAAGCTCAGCTTGGTATTGGGTCATCGTCTGGTCACACAGGCGTGCCTGAAAATCAGTGGCGGTGCCCATCCGGCTTCAAGCATAGTAATTTCTATCTTGCTTTGGAAGTCTCCGGAGGGTTACACCGGCCAACAACCCCAATTTTCTATG
>Dactylonectria_anthuriicola|JF735302|SH1546329.08FU|refs|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Sordariomycetes;o__Hypocreales;f__Nectriaceae;g__Dactylonectria;s__Dactylonectria_anthuriicola
CCGAGTTTTCAACTCCCAAACCCCTGTGAACATACCATTTTGTTGCCTCGGCGGTGCCTGTTCCGACAGCCCGCCAGAGGACCCCAAACCCAAATTTCCTTGAGTGAGTCTTCTGAGTAACCGATTAAATAAATCAAAACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTCTGGCATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAAATGCGATAAGTAATGTGAATTGCAGAATTCAGTGAATCATCGAATCTTTGAACGCACATTGCGCCCGCCAGTATTCTGGCGGGCATGCCTGTTCGAGCGTCATTTCAACCCTCAAGCCCCCGGGCTTGGTGTTGGGGATCGGCGAGCCTCTGCGCCCGCCGTCCCCTAAATTGAGTGGCGGTCACGTTGTAACTTCCTCTGCGTAGTAGCACACTTAGCACTGGGAAACAGCGCGGCCACGCCGTAAAACCCCCAACTTTGAACG
>Ilyonectria_robusta|JF735264|SH1546327.08FU|refs|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Sordariomycetes;o__Hypocreales;f__Nectriaceae;g__Ilyonectria;s__Ilyonectria_robusta
CCGAGTTTACAACTCCCAAACCCCTGTGAACATACCATATTGTTGCCTCGGCGGTGTCTGTTTCGGCAGCCCGCCAGAGGACCCAAACCCTAGATTACATTAAAGCATTTTCTGAGTCAATGATTAAATCAATCAAAACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTCTGGCATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAAATGCGATAAGTAATGTGAATTGCAGAATTCAGTGAATCATCGAATCTTTGAACGCACATTGCGCCCGCCAGTATTCTGGCGGGCATGCCTGTCCGAGCGTCATTTCAACCCTCAAGCCCCCGGGCTTGGTGTTGGAGATCGGCGAGCCCCCCGGGGCGCGCCGTCTCCCAAATATAGTGGCGGTCCCGCTGTAGCTTCCTCTGCGTAGTAGCACACCTCGCACTGGGAAACAGCGTGGCCACGCCGTAAAACCCCCCACTTCTGAAAG
>Symbiotaphrina_buchneri|DQ248313|SH1641879.08FU|reps|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Xylonomycetes;o__Symbiotaphrinales;f__Symbiotaphrinaceae;g__Symbiotaphrina;s__Symbiotaphrina_buchneri
ACGATTTTGACCCTTCGGGGTCGATCTCCAACCCTTTGTCTACCTTCCTTGTTGCTTTGGCGGGCCGATGTTCGTTCTCGCGAACGACACCGCTGGCCTGACGGCTGGTGCGCGCCCGCCAGAGTCCACCAAAACTCTGATTCAAACCTACAGTCTGAGTATATATTATATTAAAACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTCTGGCATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAAATGCGATAAGTAATGTGAATTGCAGAATTCAGTGAATCATCGAATCTTTGAACGCACATTGCGCCCCTTGGTATTCCGAGGGGCATGCCTGTTCGAGCGTCATTTCACCACTCAAGCTCAGCTTGGTATTGGGTCATCGTCTGGTCACACAGGCGTGCCTGAAAATCAGTGGCGGTGCCCATCCGGCTTCAAGCATAGTAATTTCTATCTTGCTTTGGAAGTCTCCGGAGGGTTACACCGGCCAACAACCCCAATTTTCTATG
```

I have tried

```
$ cat Unite/sh_general_release_dynamic_02.02.2019.fasta \
  Unite_61635/sh_general_release_dynamic_s_02.02.2019.fasta \
  > mergeUnite/MergeUnite.temp.fasta
```

After merging the file, I used `fastx_collapser` to collapse the duplicate information. However, after using fastx_collapser, I will lose the taxonomy information and become:

```
>1-234
ATCG........
```

The expected output should be:

```
>Symbiotaphrina_buchneri|DQ248313|SH1641879.08FU|reps|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Xylonomycetes;o__Symbiotaphrinales;f__Symbiotaphrinaceae;g__Symbiotaphrina;s__Symbiotaphrina_buchneri
ACGATTTTGACCCTTCGGGGTCGATCTCCAACCCTTTGTCTACCTTCCTTGTTGCTTTGGCGGGCCGATGTTCGTTCTCGCGAACGACACCGCTGGCCTGACGGCTGGTGCGCGCCCGCCAGAGTCCACCAAAACTCTGATTCAAACCTACAGTCTGAGTATATATTATATTAAAACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTCTGGCATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAAATGCGATAAGTAATGTGAATTGCAGAATTCAGTGAATCATCGAATCTTTGAACGCACATTGCGCCCCTTGGTATTCCGAGGGGCATGCCTGTTCGAGCGTCATTTCACCACTCAAGCTCAGCTTGGTATTGGGTCATCGTCTGGTCACACAGGCGTGCCTGAAAATCAGTGGCGGTGCCCATCCGGCTTCAAGCATAGTAATTTCTATCTTGCTTTGGAAGTCTCCGGAGGGTTACACCGGCCAACAACCCCAATTTTCTATG
>Dactylonectria_anthuriicola|JF735302|SH1546329.08FU|refs|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Sordariomycetes;o__Hypocreales;f__Nectriaceae;g__Dactylonectria;s__Dactylonectria_anthuriicola
CCGAGTTTTCAACTCCCAAACCCCTGTGAACATACCATTTTGTTGCCTCGGCGGTGCCTGTTCCGACAGCCCGCCAGAGGACCCCAAACCCAAATTTCCTTGAGTGAGTCTTCTGAGTAACCGATTAAATAAATCAAAACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTCTGGCATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAAATGCGATAAGTAATGTGAATTGCAGAATTCAGTGAATCATCGAATCTTTGAACGCACATTGCGCCCGCCAGTATTCTGGCGGGCATGCCTGTTCGAGCGTCATTTCAACCCTCAAGCCCCCGGGCTTGGTGTTGGGGATCGGCGAGCCTCTGCGCCCGCCGTCCCCTAAATTGAGTGGCGGTCACGTTGTAACTTCCTCTGCGTAGTAGCACACTTAGCACTGGGAAACAGCGCGGCCACGCCGTAAAACCCCCAACTTTGAACG
>Ilyonectria_robusta|JF735264|SH1546327.08FU|refs|k__Fungi;p__Ascomycota;c__Sordariomycetes;o__Hypocreales;f__Nectriaceae;g__Ilyonectria;s__Ilyonectria_robusta
CCGAGTTTACAACTCCCAAACCCCTGTGAACATACCATATTGTTGCCTCGGCGGTGTCTGTTTCGGCAGCCCGCCAGAGGACCCAAACCCTAGATTACATTAAAGCATTTTCTGAGTCAATGATTAAATCAATCAAAACTTTCAACAACGGATCTCTTGGTTCTGGCATCGATGAAGAACGCAGCGAAATGCGATAAGTAATGTGAATTGCAGAATTCAGTGAATCATCGAATCTTTGAACGCACATTGCGCCCGCCAGTATTCTGGCGGGCATGCCTGTCCGAGCGTCATTTCAACCCTCAAGCCCCCGGGCTTGGTGTTGGAGATCGGCGAGCCCCCCGGGGCGCGCCGTCTCCCAAATATAGTGGCGGTCCCGCTGTAGCTTCCTCTGCGTAGTAGCACACCTCGCACTGGGAAACAGCGTGGCCACGCCGTAAAACCCCCCACTTCTGAAAG
```

Is there another method to do this without losing taxonomy information?

Comment: You will have to explain what is "taxonomy information" and give a sample of the two input files you are merging (there is only one in the question). Also, a sample output would be advisable.

Comment: Hi Poshi, I add some example above. Hope this will be clear!

Comment: Only slightly clearer. Maybe this can help: https://www.biostars.org/p/143617/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following awk line will remove duplicate information. There are 3 ways I can see how you can detect duplicates:

**sequence name identical:**

The short version would be:

```
$ awk '/^>/{p=seen[$0]++}!p' file1.fasta file2.fasta file3.fasta ...
```

However, the following version introduces a bit more clarity and allows any user to quickly adapt it to his needs:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"; FS="\n"; ORS=""}
       (FNR==1){next}
       { name=$1; seq=$0; gsub(/(^[^\n]*|)\n/,"",seq) }
       !(seen[name]++){ print ">" $0 }' file1.fasta file2.fasta file3.fasta ...
```

Here we introduced the variable `name` which holds the sequence name, and the variable `seq` that holds the sequence itself. Multi-line sequences are moved to a single line in the variable.

As said before, this is easily adaptable when using other metrics for determining duplications. Eg.

**First part of sequence name identical:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"; FS="\n"; ORS=""}
       (FNR==1){next}
       { name=$1; seq=$0; gsub(/(^[^\n]*|)\n/,"",seq) }
       { key=substr(name,1,index(s,"|")) }
       !(seen[key]++){ print ">" $0 }' file1.fasta file2.fasta file3.fasta ...
```

**sequence identical:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"; FS="\n"; ORS=""}
       (FNR==1){next}
       { name=$1; seq=$0; gsub(/(^[^\n]*|)\n/,"",seq) }
       !(seen[seq]++){ print ">" $0 }' file1.fasta file2.fasta file3.fasta ...
```

**sequence name and sequence identical:**

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"; FS="\n"; ORS=""}
       (FNR==1){next}
       { name=$1; seq=$0; gsub(/(^[^\n]*|)\n/,"",seq) }
       !(seen[name,seq]++){ print ">" $0 }' file1.fasta file2.fasta file3.fasta ...
```

In some parts you could of-course clean up. You do not always need the `name` to determine the duplicate (see *sequence identical*) or you do not always need the `seq` (see *sequence name identical*). this allows you to remove some parts of the code. I just kept it this way, without cleanup, to show the method you could use.

**note:** the above makes use of [Remove line if field is duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604088/remove-line-if-field-is-duplicate)