# Concatenate the sequence to the ID in fasta file

Tags: awk

Here is my input file

```
>OTU1;size=4;
ATTCCGGGTTTACT
ATTCCTTTTATCGA
ATC
>OTU2;size=10;
CGGATCTAGGCGAT
ACT
>OTU3;size=5;
ATTCCCGGGATCTA
ACTTTTC
```

The expected output file is:

```
>OTU1;size=4;ATTCCGGGTTTACTATTCCTTTTATCGAATC
>OTU2;size=10;CGGATCTAGGCGATACT
>OTU3;size=5;ATTCCCGGGATCTAACTTTTC
```

I've tried the code from [Remove line breaks in a FASTA file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857088/remove-line-breaks-in-a-fasta-file)

but this doesn't work for me, and I am not sure how to modify the code from that post...
Any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another `awk` script. Using the `awk` internal parsing mechanism.

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">";OFS="";}NR>1{$1=$1;print ">"$0}' input.txt
```

Output is:

```
>OTU1;size=4;ATTCCGGGTTTACTATTCCTTTTATCGAATC
>OTU2;size=10;CGGATCTAGGCGATACT
>OTU3;size=5;ATTCCCGGGATCTAACTTTTC
```

Explanation:

```
awk '
BEGIN {        # initialize awk internal variables
  RS=">";      # set `RS`=record separator to `>`
  OFS="";      # set `OFS`=output field separator to empty string.
}
NR>1 {         # handle from 2nd record (1st record is empty).
  $1=$1;       # regenerate the output line
  print ">"$0  # print out ">" with computed output line
}' input.txt
```

Comment: Very nice usage of the internal variables.

Comment: You still need to set `FS="\n"`. Also, it might be wiser to use `FNR>1` instead of `NR>1` imagine you want to process two files.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I check the `FS` has an implicit default to `\n` and there is not way to override it (hope I understand correctly). See here https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_6.html#SEC45.

Comment: You are correct that `FS` is by default blanks or newlines, but you are incorrect that you cannot override the newline. when `FS` is two characters, it is assumed to be a regular expression, then you overwrite the newline as a field splitter. (See [POSIX awk standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) section regular expressions)

Comment: Well, turns out I stumbled across this before, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2019-04/msg00029.html, and the gawk maintainer is going to update the gawk documentation to record the difference and work to get the POSIX standard changed so it describes the way gawk (and some other awks) behaves which is to add `\n` to `FS` only when `FS` is a single char but if `FS` is a regexp then not add `\n` to it. All of this still only applies to the case where `RS` is null, of course.

Comment: @kvantour the version of the gawk manual you referenced is out of date, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line for a more recent version that addresses this behavior - `NOTE: When FS is the null string ("") or a regexp, this special feature of RS does not apply. It does apply to the default field separator of a single space: ‘FS = " "’.

    Note that language in the POSIX specification implies that this special feature should apply when FS is a regexp. However, Unix awk has never behaved that way, nor has gawk. This is essentially a bug in POSIX.`

Comment: so wrt the script in this particular answer where RS is **not** null  - you'd only need to set `FS` to `\n` if the lines contained chains of white space that you didn't want removed by `$1=$1` with `OFS=""`. Otherwise `\n` is already included in the field separator white space by the default FS of `" "` and so, like all other white space, will be stripped by `$1=$1` when `OFS=""` as it is here.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^>/ ? ors : ""), $0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
>OTU1;size=4;ATTCCGGGTTTACTATTCCTTTTATCGAATC
>OTU2;size=10;CGGATCTAGGCGATACT
>OTU3;size=5;ATTCCCGGGATCTAACTTTTC
```

Comment: Smart, concise and elegant solution. please explain the need for `ors` variable. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. You need to print null for the first line and ORS afterwards so setting that variable after the first line is processed takes care of that. It's equivalent to writing `(/^>/ ? (NR>1 > ORS : "") : ""), $0` which I consider more cryptic.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following too.

```
awk -v RS=">" 'NR>1{gsub(/\n/,"");print ">"$0}'  Input_file
```

My original attempt was `awk -v RS=">" -v FS="\n" -v OFS="" 'NF>1{$1=$1;print ">"$0}'  Input_file` but later I saw it is already answered buy dudi boy so written another(first mentioned) one.

Comment: I think you have an error in here. Should it not be (NR>1)?

Comment: Smart, concise and elegant solution.

Comment: @kvantour, thank you sir for letting know, edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56278627/how-to-merge-two-fasta-files-and-remove-the-duplicate-information/56544082#56544082):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=">"; FS="\n"; ORS=""}
       (FNR==1){next}
       { name=$1; seq=$0; gsub(/(^[^\n]*|)\n/,"",seq) }
       { print ">" name seq }' file1.fasta file2.fasta file3.fasta ...
```